# Problems when storing WebSocket connection handle objects using jQuery.data() -- what's the best thing to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, tornado, long-polling

I have an asynchronous queue worker running as a Tornado script on my server -- it hosts a subclass of Tornado's PeriodicTask, which consumes events from Redis. To monitor the queue, I set up a `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` subclass on a URL, and then encapsulated the client WebSocket JavaScript in a jQuery plugin ([here is the full code](https://github.com/fish2000/django-imagekit/blob/icc-develop/imagekit/static/imagekit/js/jquery.queuestatus.js)).

The idea is, you can have a number of queues on the server, and so you can use the jQuery module to set up a widget that specifically monitors that queue. At the moment, the logic is dead simple -- the widgets merely indicate how many tasks are enqueued in their target queue.

Here's the init code in question:

```
    /* init: */ function (_options) {
    options = $.extend(options, _options);
    var self = this;

    self.data('recently', [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    self.data('options', options);
    self.data('sock', null);

    var sock = null;
    if ('endpoint' in options && options['endpoint']) {
        sock = new WebSocket(options['endpoint']);
        sock.onopen = function () {};
        sock.onclose = function () {};
        sock.onmessage = function (e) {
            var d = $.parseJSON(e.data);
            if (options.queuename in d) {
                var qlen = d[options.queuename]
                lastvalues = self.data('recently');
                lastvalues.shift();
                lastvalues.push(qlen);
                if (lastvalues.every(function (itm) { return itm == 0; })) {
                    self.each(function () {
                        var elem = $(this);
                        elem.html("<b>Currently Idle</b>");
                    });
                } else {
                    self.each(function () {
                        var elem = $(this);
                        elem.html("<b>" + qlen + "</b> Queued Signals");
                    });
                }
                self.data('recently', lastvalues);
            }
        }
    }
    self.data('sock', sock);
    return self.each(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.data('sock', sock);
    });
}
```

The javascript uses `window.setInterval()` to periodically send a message to the socket; the server replies with the status of the queue for which it was asked, and the socket's frontend callback updates the DOM.

But the problem is: after a few minutes of this sort of polling **-- set off specifically by navigating between pages containing the client socket code --** the sockets fail by throwing an exception with a message like `DOM_ERROR_11` and a message that the socket object is no longer valid.

[image]

Once the page enters this error condition, I have to restart both the browser *and* the server websocket script to get everything to start up again.

... Is there a better way to set things up than I have (with the `window.setInterval()` and whatnot)?

Comment: `DOM_ERROR_11` means 'invalid state' so probably you have been disconnected for some reason. What is `sock.readyState` when the error is thrown (perhaps you could use a `try catch`)?

Comment: I tried a couple of approaches with `try`/`catch` blocks: see http://bit.ly/oe8JIr for the current mechanism and two other attempts in the comments... the state of the socket object was Heisenbergianly hard to ascertain, tho -- it seemed to be `null` whenever the exception was thrown, which is confusing as I would think I'd just get a null-object error in that case. Anyway I'll try it again and report back about `sock.readyState()` as soon as I can trigger the error, thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, `readyState` is not a function but a property.

Comment: Ahaha, whoops, thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: OK -- for one, the error can be easily triggered by navigating between pages containing the client socket code, once the widget has seen some traffic... see the screenshot I've added. And second: readyState = 1 when it's in this condition. I've edited the q above with the deets!

Comment: Also, I was mistaken about w/r/t `null` socket objects as per my first comment on this q.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. `readyState == 1` in fact means the connection is open so I'm not sure what the problem is. Am I correct in saying that you only get this error when navigating? In that case the handshake might not always be correct as you are opening a new socket on each new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's probably not the best idea to keep a heavy object attached to DOM

You could alternatively have a global storage (probably a dictionary) with keys to sockets mapping, and only store the key as a DOM obj attribute